Cookiecutter error message "A valid repository for "." could not be found in the following locations: ."

After doing that and open the terminal i wrote
cookiecutter .

and the message that appear is
A valid repository for "." could not be found in the following locations: .

Some one knows whats going on? I come from this other post about it
Cookiecutter: A valid repository for X could not be found in the following locations:
but nothing that was said there worked for me.
I corrected the name of the .json which was bad save and try again.
Did everything that was in the post I linked before

why do you use dot? What do you expect? it should be name of template. see cookiecutter --help

you  has to be in folder {{...slug}} (in which you have cookiecutter.json) when you run cookiecutter .. If you in run cookiecutter . in folder coookiecutter_testing then cookiecutter.json has to be in coookiecutter_testing or you have to use cookiecutter {{...slug}}

I think you have cookiecutter.json in wrong place.
It seems you have it inside {{ ... _slug }} but it has to be directly in COOKIECUTTER_TESTING
(if you run cookiecutter . in folder COOKIECUTTER_TESTING)
COOKIECUTTER_TESTING
|
+--> cookiecutter.json
|
+--> {{ ... _slug }}
     |
     +--> data
     |
     +--> notebooks
     | 
     +--> environment.yml


Thanks I test what you told me and is working now... Thanks
